# sum of counts in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to alter this stored procedure to give me the sum of counts for the column 'number'
what is the best way to go about doing that?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_report]
(
@para date = NULL               
)
as
declare @date date = coalesce(@para, cast( getdate() as date)) 

select
'ctfog' as Place,
@date as 'Date',
count(ctfog.Dassign) as number
from
(select 1 as x)x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.ctfog ON cast(Dassign as date) = @date

 union 

select     'abbup' as Place, 
        @date as 'Date',
count(abbup.Dassign) as number
from
(select 1 as x)x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.abbup ON cast(Dassign as date) = @date

union 

select     'ggiis' as Place, 
        @date as 'Date',
count(ggiis.Dassign) as number
(select 1 as x)x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.ggiis ON cast(Dassign as date) = @date
```

my current table looks like this

### place  | date  | number

ctfog |  1/1/1111|    8

abbup | 1/1/1111 |   9

ggiis |  1/1/1111|    4

and i need something like this

### place  | date  | number

ctfog |  1/1/1111 |   8

abbup |  1/1/1111  |  10

ggiis  | 1/1/1111 |   4

Total |  1/1/1111 |  22

Comment: You can insert all that data into a temp table and then do the calculation and insert that row in the same temp table

Comment: thought about that, but i would like it to be done right away in the stored procedure if somehow possible  i am trying to figure out if it could be done by using subqueris

Comment: I am also unable to create a temp table because i am getting this error Incorrect syntax near '@para'.

Comment: I assume that this must be sql server due to getdate???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do with these in those queries.

> (select 1 as x)x

COUNT will return 0 when there are no rows that meet the criteria of the query so this is totally unnecessary.

I removed the column aliases after the first query because they are ignored anyway. I also changed this to use UNION ALL because UNION will check for and remove duplicates which isn't possible since you have string literals in each query.

Pretty sure you can use something along these lines.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_report]
(
    @para date = NULL               
)
as
    declare @date date = coalesce(@para, cast( getdate() as date)) 
    with GroupedData as
    (
        select
            'ctfog' as Place,
            @date as 'Date',
            count(ctfog.Dassign) as number
        from dbo.ctfog 
        where cast(Dassign as date) = @date

        union ALL

        select
            'abbup', 
            @date,
            count(abbup.Dassign)
        from dbo.abbup
        where cast(Dassign as date) = @date

        union ALL

        select
            'ggiis', 
            @date,
            count(ggiis.Dassign)
        from dbo.ggiis
        where cast(Dassign as date) = @date
    )       

    select Place
        , Date
        , number
    from GroupedData

    UNION ALL
    select 'Total'
        , @date
        , SUM(number)
    from GroupedData
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, i didn't try but i think it works.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_report]
(
@para date = NULL               
)
as

declare @date date = coalesce(@para, cast( getdate() as date)) 
declare @temp_table as table(place nvarchar(100),date_ datetime, number int)

insert into @temp_table
select
'ctfog' as Place,
@date as 'Date',
count(ctfog.Dassign) as number
from
(select 1 as x)x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.ctfog ON cast(Dassign as date) = @date

insert into @temp_table
select     'abbup' as Place, 
    @date as 'Date',
count(abbup.Dassign) as number
from
(select 1 as x)x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.abbup ON cast(Dassign as date) = @date

insert into @temp_table
select     'ggiis' as Place, 
    @date as 'Date',
count(ggiis.Dassign) as number
(select 1 as x)x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.ggiis ON cast(Dassign as date) = @date

select place, date_, sum(number) number
into #temp
from @temp_table
group by place, date_ with rollup

update #temp set place='TOTAL', date_ = @date where date_ is null

select *
from #temp
```